# How can I solve the differential equation $f'(x) + f\left( x^2\right) =0$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, contest-math, functional-equations

I was looking at [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1765346p11556039) AOPS thread which dealt with the following question:

> Find all functions $f:(1, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ that satisfy $$f(x) -f(y) = (y-x)f(xy)  $$

I attempted to solve (at least part of) this question, and in one of my attempts I encountered a path that seemed promising, but I couldn't manage to finish the solution. Here's what I did:

---

Rewriting the functional equation as
$$
\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x-y} = -f(xy)
$$
the LHS is the slope of a secant line. This makes me want to take the limit $y\to x$ on both sides to get some derivatives. So assuming $f$ is differentiable on the domain of interest, this gives
$$
f'(x) = -f\left(x^2\right) \tag{1}
$$
as a differential equation whose solutions form a subset of differentiable solutions to our original functional equation.

As shown in the AOPS thread, the family of solutions to the original problem is indeed $f(x) = \frac{c}{x}$, with $c$ some constant, and this family of functions do satisfy that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x}\frac{c}{x} = -\frac{c}{x^2}$ as the differential equation suggests, so all seems good up to this point.

---

Even though using the ansatz $f(x) = \frac{c}{x}$ to verify the differential equation $(1)$ does work, I don't know how to solve the differential equation directly. I thought about introducing a substitution of the form $u(x) = x^2$, but then the LHS of $(1)$ would end up with things like $f'(\sqrt{u})$ which again doesn't seem very useful.

Is it possible to solve the differential equation $(1)$ directly? And if the answer is yes, what is the procedure with which you can go about solving a differential equation like this? Thank you!

Comment: Notice that although you manage to finish your solution this does not give every function $f$, just differentiable functions.

Comment: @Marcos, thank you for your comment! I also noticed this, which is why I wrote that the solution of the differential equation would be subset of the solution family, and not the whole solution family. My goal for this question isn't to find all solutions to the functional equation, but I added this information to comply with the context-policy of the site so that people can know where the differential equation came from.

Comment: Then all good :) I'm not good at solving differeintial equations, but I hope someone can help you.

Comment: "a differential equation whose solutions form a subset of differentiable solutions to our original functional equation" is incorrect. As you obtained the differential equation from the given functional equation, the functional equation is stronger. Thus, differentiable solutions to the functional equation is a subset of the differentiable solutions to (1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the domain of $f$ in $f'(x)=-f(x^2)$ is $(1,\infty)$ as given in the linked AOPS problem, then we can find a solution which is not of the form of $c/x$ for constant $c$.

Note that if $f(x)=c/x$, then necessarily $c=2f(2)$ by putting $x=2$. With this choice of $f$, we have $F(x)=f(x)-\frac{2f(2)}x = 0$.

For any $f$ satisfying $f'(x)=-f(x^2)$, we have $F(x)=f(x)-\frac{2f(2)}x$ also satisfies $F'(x)=-F(x^2)$ and we have $F(2)=0$. By constructing a nonzero function $F$  with
$$F'(x)=-F(x^2), \ \ F(2)=0. \ \ (1)$$
we see that not every function with $f'(x)=-f(x^2)$ is of the form $f(x)=c/x$.

Define $F(x)$ on $[2,4]$ [the bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) on the interval $[2,4]$. Then we define $F(x)$ on $[4,16]$ by $F(x)=-F'(\sqrt x)$. The bump function is infinitely differentiable and we need $F'(x)$ on $[2,4]$ to define $F(x)$ on $[4,16]$. We repeat this procedure to define $F(x)$ on $[16,256]$, $[256, 65536]$,  $\ldots$, in general $[2^{2^k}, 2^{2^{k+1}}]$ for $k\geq 0$. Then $F(x)$ satisfies $(1)$ for all $x\geq 2$.

To define the function on the interval $(1,2)$, we use
$$
F(x)=\int_x^2 F(t^2)dt.
$$
We need $F(x)$ on $[2,4]$ to define $F(x)$ on $[\sqrt 2, 2]$ by the above formula. To define $F(x)$ on $[\sqrt[4]{2},\sqrt 2]$ we need $F(x)$ on $[\sqrt 2, 4]$. Repeating the procedure, we are able to define $F(x)$ on $[2^{2^k}, 2^{2^{k+1}}]$ for any negative integer $k$. Thus, $F(x)$ is defined for all $x\in (1,2)$.

Combining these together, we have a nonzero function $F$ satisfying $(1)$ on $(1,\infty)$.

Comment: "We consider $F(x)=f(x)-\frac{2f(2)}x$. Then $F(x)$ also satisfies $F'(x)=-F(x^2)$ and we have $F(2)=0$." Isn't $F(x)$ here just the zero function?

Comment: Yes, when $f(x)=c/x$, $F(x)$ is the zero function. My point here is that not all solutions are of the form $f(x)=c/x$.

Answer (score 1):

With $a_0 := 1$, $a_k := (-1)^k/\prod_{j=1}^k\, (2^j - 1)$ for $k > 0$, another linearly independent solution is
\begin{equation*}
g(x) := \sum_{k=0}^\infty\, a_k\,x^{2^k - 1}.
\end{equation*}
There's a note on this in [OEIS A005329](https://oeis.org/A005329). To answer the 'how can I solve' part, try a Laurent series expansion.